# RegEx - if then else

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, grouping

I am trying to work out a regex expression but struggle with conditionals. I have a list of 100s of URLs that look like this:

1. /name/something/details/55334
2. /name/page/1/2
3. /name/somethingdifferent/34523
4. /name/page/1
5. /name/something/553/1

Bottom line is that I want to remove everything when a number appears apart from a scenario where the last thing before the number is a word 'page'.

```
1. /name/something/details/
2. /name/page/1/2
3. /name/somethingdifferent/
4. /name/page/1
5. /name/something
```

I will be removing it with Google Analytics Content Grouping or potentially with DataStudio. I already removed /name/ so I have:

```
1. /something/details/55334
2. /page/1/2
3. /somethingdifferent/34523
4. /page/1
5. /something/553/1
```

but want to add another rule and remove the numbers so I get:

```
1. /something/details/
2. /page/1/2
3. /somethingdifferent/
4. /page/1
5. /something
```

have already tried:

```
\(?(?=(page\/[0-9]+))(\2)|(\/\d+)
```

following the syntax of:

```
(?(?=condition))(IF)|(ELSE)
```

but it highlights all numbers after text.

Thanks for your help.

sampak

Comment: Should the 5th one be `/something` or `/something/`

Comment: sorry, should be /something/

Comment: Did  the pattern I suggested work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(\/page.*|[^0-9]*)`, works with your example.

A Version incl. name: `^(page[\/\d]*|[^\d\s])*`

Comment: How would I make it match the number after the text only? Your solution works well for including anything but the numbers, if I wanted to add extraction rule in Google Analytics, so I possibly extract /name/ and the numbers after anything but page or just the numbers after page. Thanks

Comment: Can you write a little example what you mean? Input and expected output, at the moment I do not understand what you try to say to me.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to match not a whitespace or digit while not  matching /page.

Then match a forward slash and 1+ digits followed by any char 0+ times to omit that from the result.

```
^((?:(?!\/page)[^\d\s])*\/)\d.*
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\/page)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not
    - `[^\d\s]` Match any char except a digit or whitespace char
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\/` Match `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\d.*` Match a digit followed by any char except a newline 0+ times

In the replacement use the first capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DS6P55/1)

If you also want to remove `/name` you could use:

```
^\/name((?:(?!\/page)[^\d\s])*\/)\d.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRbbjr/1)

Comment: when I check it with www.regextester.com then it highlights the entire line instead of just the numbers in the lines where page is not present.

Comment: @user3015289 That is correct, but you should replace the match with the first capturing group. At this demo link https://regex101.com/r/gRbbjr/1 you can see that the first capturing group is highlighted in green and that will be the replacement.

Comment: is this how Google Analytics will understand it ? if yes, then I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: @user3015289 I see what you mean. I think google analytics [regex](https://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/regular-expressions-for-google-analytics) does not support a negative lookahead `(?!` Can you test it with this pattern and still use group 1 in the replacement? `^\/name(.*\/page\/[0-9].*|[^0-9]+).*` https://regex101.com/r/nLXv8z/1

Comment: I use this to remove name which is really any string, name is just an example: /[-a-zA-Z]+/(.*) and then it groups everything that comes after, and I want to get rid of some of IDs that appear at the end of the URLs - to give you a better understanding

Comment: @user3015289 This pattern will match any char except a `/` or a digit from the start `^\/[^\/0-9]*(\/page\/[0-9].*|[^0-9]+).*` and will match from a digit till the end https://regex101.com/r/fdmWOm/1. If you replace with the first capturing group you would get the specified results from the question.